# Does it make sense to install the Frontpage Server extensions on a production server for (ASP).NET applications?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce, frontpage

Visual Studio offers some built-in deployment features that require **Frontpage Server Extensions** to be installed on the web server:

- publishing of ASP.NET applications,
- publishing of Windows applications accessible through ClickOnce.

Right now, I deploy such applications manually by copying the relevant files with a WebDAV client.

It's not a lot of work, but it feels like I'm doing unnecessary work, since there's already a built-in feature of Visual Studio that would do this automatically for me.

On the other hand, I have a strong gut feeling that warns me against doing so: Right now, I have a good understanding of which protocols can be used to access the server, which users can do so, and which parts of the server they can access. Since I don't understand everything that the "magic CGIs" of the Frontpage Server Extensions are doing, I fear that I might accidentally open some security hole due to lack of knowledge.

As a .NET developer, what is your take on this? Did I miss some obvious advantage/disadvantage? Or is there even some established "best practice" in the community w.r.t. using the Frontpage Server Extensions for .NET web servers?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use Frontpage extensions anymore, you can use [MSDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy).  Rejoice!

**Edit**: Also see this blog post about doing [continuous integration with MSDeploy](http://therightstuff.de/CommentView,guid,fc544216-b269-4f06-bdc6-972bb2dbc88a.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that will be useful once we don't need to support IIS6 anymore.